# Sql Server Management Studio 18.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I recently installed SSMS 18.1 and I am having an issue when trying to drag and drop table names from the object explorer to the query window. For example, I am writing a query and dont want type out the table name I would drag and drop the table into the query editor and the name will be there.

This is the error I get:
"An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any add-ons enabled?  If you have any add-ons you should remove them

Comment: It turns out this is an issue and Microsoft is rolling out the fix in the next update to SSMS 18. Here's the link:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37887988